# How to sort fields of a document based on the nested position value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say, I have two documents in a collection stored in MongoDB:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("64cfe7bf9f45fdfdb2eadcb2"),
    userId: 101,
    title: { value: 'mr', isSelected: true, position: 1 },
    firstName: { value: 'John', isSelected: true, position: 4 },
    middleName: { value: 'M.', isSelected: true, position: 2 },
    lastName: { value: 'Doe', isSelected: true, position: 3 }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64cfe7bf9f45fdfdb2eadcb3"),
    userId: 102,
    title: { value: 'ms', isSelected: true, position: 1 },
    firstName: { value: 'Janna', isSelected: true, position: 2 },
    middleName: { value: 'R', isSelected: true, position: 3 },
    lastName: { value: 'Lee', isSelected: true, position: 4 }
  }
```

I will pass the userId value to the query and in return I wanted the document to be returned with the document's fields in an order defined in the position value.

Expected result if userId is 101:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("64cfe7bf9f45fdfdb2eadcb2"),
    userId: 101,
    title: { value: 'mr', isSelected: true, position: 1},
    middleName: { value: 'M.', isSelected: true, position: 2},
    lastName: { value: 'Doe', isSelected: true, position: 3}
    firstName: { value: 'John', isSelected: true, position: 4},
    }
```

Note that field names are in different order (*title*, *middleName*, *lastName*, and *firstName*).

And, if *userID* is 102 then:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("64cfe7bf9f45fdfdb2eadcb3"),
    userId: 102,
    title: { value: 'ms', isSelected: true, position: 1},
    firstName: { value: 'Janna', isSelected: true, position: 2},
    middleName: { value: 'R', isSelected: true, position: 3},
    lastName: { value: 'Lee', isSelected: true, position: 4}
    }
```

Notice the field names are in a different order than the first query (title, firstName, middleName, lastName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do (I usually avoid any object field ordering importance.), this aggregation pipeline may be sufficient.  It's a bit specific and not flexible, so it would need adjustment if the document model changes. (See below **EDIT** for a more rubust aggregation pipeline.)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userId": 101  // "I will pass the userId value to the query..."
    }
  },
  { // rewrite/replace entire document
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        // object of everything except the fields that are sorted
        {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "userId": "$userId"
        },
        // object of fields ordered by position
        {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$sortArray": {
              "input": [
                {"k": "title", "v": "$title"},
                {"k": "firstName", "v": "$firstName"},
                {"k": "middleName", "v": "$middleName"},
                {"k": "lastName", "v": "$lastName"},
              ],
              "sortBy": {"v.position": 1}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

N.B.: Unfortunately the MongoDB Go driver that mongoplayground.net uses always does an alphanumeric sort of objects by field names, so demonstrating this there is problematic.

##### EDIT

Here's a more robust aggregation pipeline that partitions the document by the presence of a numeric `position` field in a root-level object.  This makes designating the root-level field names irrelevant.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userId": 101
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "fieldPartition": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
          "initialValue": {
            "withPosition": [],
            "withoutPosition": []
          },
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {"$isNumber": "$$this.v.position"},
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "withPosition": {
                      "$concatArrays": ["$$value.withPosition", ["$$this"]]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "withoutPosition": {
                      "$concatArrays": ["$$value.withoutPosition", ["$$this"]]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$fieldPartition.withoutPosition",
          {
            "$sortArray": {
              "input": "$fieldPartition.withPosition",
              "sortBy": {"v.position": 1}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @rickhg12hs, It is working as expected. Do you think the data structure could have been better for this use case? How would you structure this data, assuming that on UI you are giving Drag & Drop functionality to rearrange the columns?

Comment: @ritu_o0o I'm not really sure where to store and process presentation details.  My first impressions (could be convinced otherwise):  I think I would make sure that any necessary data associated specifically with a user is in the user document (I don't know why presentation order would be there, but OK.).  All the presentation processing I think I would keep wherever presentation is performed.  It seems a bit awkward that to change the style of some presentation, I'd need to change/add database code.

Comment: @ritu_o0o I added another aggregation pipeline to the answer that is a bit more robust by partitioning the document by looking for numeric `position` fields in a root-level field object.